# Notification for Memory Shortage Issue in Server

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring

I have a ubuntu server, and facing frequent space issue, i.e. logs are eating up lot of memories. So, I want a check to be applied, so that whenever there is less than 5 GB disk space, I should get an e-mail notification, so that I can delete the logs. How can I configure this. Do I need any other application?

Comment: You can however, a better solution is likely to add more disk space, (Unless you like getting urgent emails in the middle of the night)  You can buy 4 TB (4,000 GB) for less than $200. You might still need a program to check disk usage, but you show never expect to get this email.

Comment: I think this is better to ask at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a cron job that checks the disk space at regular times and sends you an email if it's too low. Something like the following should work. It runs once a day and uses 90% as limit:

```
0 0 * * * ((`df -l --total | tail -1 | awk '{ print int($5) }'` > 90)) && mail -s "Disk full" user@example.com < /dev/null
```

If you don't want or can't send email from your server, or need high reliability, I'd flip the logic and use an external watchdog timer. [Here's](http://cookbook.wdt.io/disk_space.html) how to do it with WDT.io.